# import <channel-name> => not found

Tags: nix

I'm following nix pills [1], which doesn't work anymore with the newest channel release [2].

```
$ echo 'graph test { a -- b }'|result/bin/dot -Tpng -o test.png
Format: "png" not recognized. ...
```

So I took the advice to use an old channel [3] (and replace `binutils` with `binutils-unwrapped`).

```
nix-channel --add https://nixos.org/channels/nixpkgs-release-14.12
```

Which works perfectly fine.

```
nixpkgs https://nixos.org/channels/nixpkgs-unstable
nixpkgs-release-14.12 https://nixos.org/channels/nixpkgs-release-14.12
```

But when I try to use it via `import <nixpkgs-release-14.12>`

I get

```
error: file 'nixpkgs-release-14.12' was not found in the Nix search path
```

- [1] https://nixos.org/nixos/nix-pills/inputs-design-pattern.html
- [2] https://github.com/NixOS/nix-pills/issues/107
- [3] https://github.com/NixOS/nix-pills/issues/107#issuecomment-470992383

Answer (score 1):

I hacked it via

```
import (fetchTarball https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs-channels/archive/nixos-14.12.tar.gz)
```

Works, but I'm not sure it's the optimal solution.

Answer (score 1):

You have to download it with the `nix-channel --update` command, but that won't work because the channel has been removed. You'll have to use a newer channel and run `--update`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by checking out the version you want with git in a directory and setting `NIX_PATH`. Otherwise, it's either not available and/or your other packages in the newer channel would supersede it. You'd have to call your command with `NIX_PATH=$mynixcheckoutdir` prepended.